# Matlab exception while using C# wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-compiler

I've made a dll version of a [clustering algorithm implemented in matlab](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/affinitypropagation/software/apclusterSparse.m)

Also, I've downloaded an [working sample of the input data](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/affinitypropagation/webapp/) (I'm using the Toy Problem data) and I'm reading it and also converting it to a Matlab known data type.

However, when running the algorithm I get the following error:

> ... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ... Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. Error in => apclusterSparse.m at line 178.

Here is my code: (sorry?)

```
public static double[,] ReadSimilarities()
    {
        string line;
        string[] splittedLine;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Code\\FCT\\Thesis\\similarities.txt");

        List<List<string>> values = new List<List<string>>();

        List<string> lineValues;

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            splittedLine = line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            lineValues = new List<string>(splittedLine.Count());

            for (int i = 0; i < splittedLine.Count(); i++)
            {
                lineValues.Add(splittedLine[i]);
            }

            values.Add(lineValues);
        }

        file.Close();

        double[,] result = new double[values.Count, 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            result[i, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(values.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(0));
            result[i, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(values.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(1));
            result[i, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(values.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(2));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static double[] ReadPreferences()
    {
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Code\\FCT\\Thesis\\preferences.txt");
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            values.Add(line);
        }

        double[] result = new double[values.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Convert.ToDouble(values.ElementAt(i));
        }

        return result;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ApClusterSparse apClusterSparse = new ApClusterSparse();

        double[,] similarities = ReadSimilarities();
        double[] preferences = ReadPreferences();

        MWNumericArray matLabSimiliaritiesArray = new MWNumericArray(similarities);
        MWNumericArray matLabPreferencesArray = new MWNumericArray(preferences);

        MWArray argsOut;

        try
        {
            argsOut = apClusterSparse.apclusterSparse(matLabSimiliaritiesArray, matLabPreferencesArray);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return View();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested it in purely MATLAB? Sounds like it's expecting a input of a different shape than what you're giving it (e.g. column vs. row vector).

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually this samples are for online demos that use this algorithm...

Comment: Actually, I've tried with more than one example and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the argument P must not be an array (as is on the website input) but instead, a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick look at line 178 of your code, it looks like you're concatenating an Nx2 array with `p`, and then concatenating that with `s`, where sometimes N is defined as `length(p)`, sometimes as `size(s,1)` and sometimes as something called `tmp`.

I'm not going to debug this, but I would suggest that to do so you should modify your code so that before line 178 it displays, or somehow outputs, the values of `N`, `p`, `s` and `tmp`. This will give you an idea of why they can't be concatenated - I'm guessing that they have different dimensions.

I'd also suggest:

1. Stop using `length`, and use either `numel` or `size` consistently. `length` gives you the same answer if its input is 10x1 or 1x10, and is not the right thing to use to check the dimensions of an array before concatenating.
2. Stop putting multiple statements on a single line, especially complete `if` statements. If there's an error, you don't know which statement caused it.
3. Improve your variable naming. It's not surprising this is tough to debug when you have variables called `A`, `a`, `s`, `ss`, `as`, `r`, `R`, `rp`, `p`, `E`, `e`, `ee`, `idx`, `ind1`, `ind1s`, `ind1e`, `ind2s`, `ind2e` and `tmpidx`. It makes my head hurt to read through it.

Comment: How I understand your comments. However note that this code is not mine and i've tried it (and working) with the algorithm inner samples. However, only when I try to run it in C# (after I've generated the dll with Matlab Builder NE) I get this error...

Comment: So if it's the exact same code, just compiled, then C# must be giving it different inputs. Perhaps it's passing `matlabPreferencesArray` as an Nx1 rather than 1xN, or maybe `matlabSimilaritiesArray` is a vector of length (NxN) instead of an NxN array. Like I suggested, modify the code so that it displays its state just before the erroring line 178 - then you'll be able to tell why MATLAB cannot do the concatenation.